# How to provide option to purchase app within app (UWP - Windows 10)

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Is there a way to provide a user with the option to buy an app within the app (by this I mean your own app) itself? I'd swear I've seen this before and maybe it was only in windows phone but I'd like to offer this within my UWP app.

I thought of redirecting the user to the store (still have to figure this one) but I didn't think it would be too user friendly having to be redirected first, then what? Uninstall the app and re-install or would the app know by inspecting the local WindowsStoreProxy.xml?

I've read about IAP, but I don't think purchasing the full app falls in that category.

I'm not even sure that's what it's doing but I just can't find any clear explanations on how the whole process is done.

Between Advertising and licensing, I don't know which one is worse!! Very poorly explained by Microsoft. There's lots of documentation but huge holes in them making it hard to decipher what is probably a simple process!

Any feedback, links to relevant articles would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I searched for "uwp iap" and found: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-in-app-product-purchases?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To purchase the app itself, we can set a **Base price** and **Free trial** for the app when you create a submission. For more info, please see [Set app pricing and availability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/set-app-pricing-and-availability).

And in the app, we can pick the features that we want to enable or disable during the trial period. See [Exclude or limit features in a trial version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/exclude-or-limit-features-in-a-trial-version-of-your-app) for details.

When the trial expires, you can refer to the following options to handle them:

> - **Trial license expires while the app is running**
>
>   If the trial expires while your app is running, your app can:
>
>   - Do nothing.
>   - Display a message to your customer.
>   - Close.
>   - Prompt your customer to buy the app.
>
>   The best practice is to display a message with a prompt for buying the app, and if the customer buys it, continue with all features enabled. If the user decides not to buy the app, close it or remind them to buy the app at regular intervals.
> - **Trial license expires before the app is launched**
>
>   If the trial expires before the user launches the app, your app won't launch. Instead, users see a dialog box that gives them the option to purchase your app from the Store.

To buy the app, we can call [CurrentApp.RequestAppPurchaseAsync | requestAppPurchaseAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.requestapppurchaseasync.aspx). This method requests the purchase of a full app license.

There is also a [Store sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Store) in Github which demonstrates trials and purchasing  the app itself. You can refer to its first Trials-Mode scenario. But please note, in this sample, it uses [CurrentAppSimulator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator) class for testing. You must replace the CurrentAppSimulator class with the [CurrentApp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp) class before you submit the app to the Windows Store.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer as it is more detailed than what Ari provided, but it is pretty much saying the same thing as what @Ari said. I ended deciding to go with the free app scenario and provide IAPs to enable all my features.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way that i know of to charge a user for an app that has already been downloaded from the windows store.

The options are:

1) Create a "lite" or "trial" version of your app that [deeplinks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/link-to-your-app) to the full version of the app in the store when the trial period expires.

2) Use an IAP to either unlock access to the full functionality of your app or authenticate a download for new content (if the app is a data driven application). A good example of an app that does this is Davis's Drug Guide for Windows phone 8.1

Comment: Hi, thanks for this link but I've already read it and all the other related links in there as well, but it doesn't mention if it is possible or not to provide a "Buy" option from within your app when the trial expires and/or how it should be handled.

Comment: Just to confirm that I got this right, with Option 1, should 2 separate apps be created? One for trial and one for full? If I go with Option 2, I should be able to provide a free app with single in-app purchase which would turn my app into a full-app and this should be doable within the app. Sounds like option 2 is the way to go. I'll update after I've done more research on IAP. Thanks.